# Python - controlling parallel port

Tags: python, parallel-port

If I understand it right this would send a signal to all pins on the parallel port? Let's say I have diodes connected to parallel port.How would I ,with the press of 'Enter', shut down all diodes or change the pattern?

```
import parallel
import time
p = parallel.Parallel()

for var in range(0,256):
p.setData(var)
print var
time.sleep(.5)

p.setData(0x00)

print "Good bye!"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python set Parallel Port data pins high/low](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902240/python-set-parallel-port-data-pins-high-low)